# ftp_get not working with large file

Tags: php, ftp

This is my code:

```
$con = ftp_connect('ftpserver.com');
ftp_login($con, 'username', 'password');
ftp_pasv($con, true);
ftp_set_option($con, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 180);
ftp_get($con, './test.txt', '/path/to/file.txt', FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($con);
```

I'm getting this error after the script runs for more than a few minutes:

`PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Opening ASCII mode data connection for /path/to/file.txt (6137508 bytes). In /path/to/script.php`

When it's running I can see the test.txt file is created and even some data shows up in it but it very abruptly stops downloading at about 23,135 bytes. After the script throws the warning test.txt gets removed.

**UPDATE**

I came up with a work around.

```
function getFile() {
    $fh = fopen('test.txt', 'a');

    $con = ftp_connect('ftpserver.com');
    ftp_login($con, 'username', 'password');
    ftp_pasv($con, true);
    ftp_set_option($con, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 1);

    if (file_exists('test.txt')) {
        $size  = ftp_size($con, '/path/to/file.txt');
        $size2 = filesize('test.txt');
        @ftp_fget($con, $fh, '/path/to/file.txt', FTP_ASCII, $size2);
        fclose($fh);
        clearstatcache();
        if (filesize('test.txt') !== $size) {
            getFile();
        }
    }
    else
        @ftp_fget($con, $fh, '/path/to/file.txt', FTP_ASCII);

    ftp_close($con);
}

getFile();
```

Comment: You need to increase the timeout then. 180 is in seconds, which is 3 minutes. Try setting it to 600. I.e.: `FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 600` or higher, depending on how much more time is needed. You probably could even try `FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 0` which I think is NO time limit (not 100% sure), or just remove it altogether. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-set-option.php for more info.

Comment: It could also be php's max execution time that you could change with: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` at the top of your script.

Comment: PHP's timeout is already set to 0. Setting FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC to a high value does the same. The script just runs for a while, the file is immediately created with the same file size of 23,135 bytes every time then gets removed. I tried to use ftp_fget and the file stays, but same size.

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine, or on a hosted site? @VitaliyIsikov Plus, is that your "actual" code, including the paths?

Comment: Haha, no. The actual code has the correct credentials and path. It's running on a dedicated linux box. The ftp server itself is unknown but I can access and get the file with an ftp client.

Comment: Haha yeah I didn't think so neither. I actually meant if this line was `ftp_get($con, './test.txt', '/path/to/file.txt', FTP_ASCII);` or similar to it. Have you tried setting both to either relative or absolute paths?

Comment: Right now the remote file path is set to an absolute path and the local file path is relative. I'll try you suggestions right now.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for this either.

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then.

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with the server I'm trying to get data off of. I'm about to post an edit to my work around.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44930/discussion-between-vitaliy-isikov-and-fred-ii)